# Dividing and Multiplying throws error if number is less than 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

```
// convert the number to it's standard value (kilogram)
standard  = parseFloat(unit / from);
// now convert it to the new measurement unit
converted = parseFloat(standard * eval(to));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zeByX/23/

If you enter a number less than one, for example '0.234234234' and try converting to a new unit by changing the drop-down. Any number less than 1 and it'll go to zero.

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Why `eval` `eval` `eval`???

Comment: Always quote ***all*** of the relevant code **in the question itself**, don't just link.

Comment: eval is used because I'm grabbing data-unit from an input, which basically tells me which variable to use: gram, kilogram etc.

Comment: You dont need eval for that.  Btw dont parse int if you want a fractional value. Eval is evil

Comment: @T.J. Crowder all relevant code has been included. The issue is with the math I believe.

Comment: @Chaplin: *"all relevant code has been included"* Wrong. *"The issue is with the math I believe."* Wrong.

Comment: @latr0dectus if I remove the eval it stops working.

Comment: @Chaplin You don't need eval to evaluate expressions. JavaScript does that automatically.

Comment: @Chaplin Put those unit values in an object literal and use the option value as an index. Also, you don't need (or want) to use `eval(to)` if `to` is already a number.

Comment: There are many issues, you're missing a bunch of semicolons, `unit`, `to`, `standard` and `converted` are global (trouble), etc...

Comment: @Chaplin: *"eval is used because I'm grabbing data-unit from an input"* You don't need or want `eval` anywhere in what you're doing. Also, you're using `parseFloat` in at least one place where you shouldn't be. Recommend stepping back, walking through a few basic JavaScript tutorials, and checking your understanding each step of the way. When you have a basic understanding, rewrite your code, and if it doesn't behave as expected, talk through it with a debugger (there's almost certainly one built into whatever browser you're using). ***Then***, if you still have a problem, post a question.

Comment: You're using `parseInt` on floats, too. Once you change `parseInt` to `parseFloat`, it works. Perhaps this was something from when you didn't deal with imperial units yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the error is caused because of the usage of `parseInt()` where you should have used `parseFloat()`, there's a whole lot more *wrong* with your code.

- `eval()` is evil, and you're using it where you don't even need it or could easily replace it with a far better solution.

  - `eval(to)` is unnecessary since `to` is already a number.
  - In the other cases, `eval` is used to use a string to access a global variable. This is a *very bad idea*, and it's much more appropriate to store your unit/value mappings in an object literal, such as `var units = { gram: 1000, kilogram: 1, ... }` Then, you can access the value by simply using the string as index, such as `unit["milligram"]`.
- You don't need `parseFloat()` when you already have a number, such as with `unit / from` or `standard * to)`
- All your variable declarations (except from `from`) in the function are global, because you're missing the `var` keyword in front.

Here's a somewhat ["fixed" fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/p2tPe/).

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to avoid `eval` and make your code cleaner and more obvious, hope this helps understand why your code was so wrong and why IMO you should go back to the basics and start from there as suggested in the comments. You can get started at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript).

```
var units = {
    milligram: 1000000,
    carrat: 5000,
    gram: 1000,
    kilogram: 1,
    ounce: 35.27399072294044,
    pound: 2.2046244201837775,
    stone: 0.157473,
    ton: 0.001
};

var $input = $('#weight_value');    

$('#weight_unit').change(function() {

    var from = $input.data('unit'),
        to = $(this).val(),
        standard = $input.val() / units[ from ],
        converted = standard * units[ to ];

    $input.val( converted ).data('unit', to);

});
```

Also note that I'm not using `parseFloat` or `parseInt`, I'm just taking advantage of JavaScript's type coercion.

​
**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/zeByX/30/

Comment: Nice one with the type coercion!

Answer (score 0):

Put the change code at a try block and catch the exception to see what is wrong.

You could use the value option on select list to store the conversion unit from a commom conversion unit.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no error thrown..

---

The specific problem you describe happens because you do

```
unit = parseInt($('#weight_value').val());
```

So if a value is between 0 and 1 it becomes 0. Change it to

```
unit = parseFloat($('#weight_value').val());
```

---

Other than that, there is invalid html (*like the self closing `select` tag and openly left `label`*), you are using `eval` which you really should not (*as explained/emphasized in the comments*)